# Can I using one Model for two entities in Room persistence?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-database

I would like to know that, is it possible to use one model for two entities while using Room Persistence in Kotlin?

For example, I have to create two pagers which are general page and star page.
Both of them have fields following..

> id: String?, caption: String?, imageUrl:String?, isUserLike: Boolean
>   (And more)

Data came from two separate services and I want to save it separately.
How can I do this, or there have any ways to solve this problem?

Thank you

P.S. I'm the beginner of Kotlin and Room persistence.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate abstract class that contains all those common fields

```
abstract class BaseModel(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String? = null,
    var caption: String? = null,
    var imageUrl: String? = null,
    ...
) {
    ...
}
```

then have that abstract class be extended on the other classes

```
@Entity(tableName = "a_model")
data class AModel (
    mId: String? = null,
    mCaption: String? = null,
    mImageUrl: String? = null,
    ...
): BaseModel(id = mId,
        caption = mCaption, 
        imageUrl = mImageUrl,
        ...) {
    ...
}
```

you can also add other fields that are exclusive to that entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "b_model")
data class BModel (
    mId: String? = null,
    mCaption: String? = null,
    mImageUrl: String? = null,
    ...
    var nonCommonField: String? = null, // like this
): BaseModel(id = mId,
        caption = mCaption, 
        imageUrl = mImageUrl,
        ...) {
    ...
}
```

Android Room will require fields to have a default value for each field or an empty constructor, if I remember correctly.